# Thymeleaf-How to pass variable

Tags: xml, thymeleaf

```
 <th:block th:with="Reference=${op.jpText('$.u_reference')}">
       <Incident id="Reference">enter code here
       <Incident>
```

I have created one reference value and as per requirement it is needed to be passed dynamically for output will be Incident id="ABCD"

When i am running the code i am getting output as Incident id="Reference"
It seems system is not able to pass the variable refernce value

Answer (score 0):

To have thymeleaf evaluate something, it must begin with `th:`.  Your code should look like

```
<Incident th:id="${Reference}">enter code here
```